# Google Apps Script "failed while accessing document"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I was recently tasked with building a slideshow from a shared Google Drive folder containing images of several different formats. After trying several Slides add-ons, I decided to "bite the bullet" and write an Apps Script, which actually wasn't as difficult as I had imagined. The script, which is attached below, ran correctly for several days, but now throws the following error: `Exception: Service Slides failed while accessing document with id [removed, but was the correct document ID]. at updateSlideshow(Update Slideshow:18:68)`.

I've done a bit of research, and it doesn't look like this particular error is very common.

A few other notes that could be relevant:

1. The script is running container-bound to the Slides document in question, which is the picture slideshow.
2. The script takes a while to complete (265 seconds on its last successful run).

Here's the full Apps Script:

```
function updateSlideshow() {
  // Setup
  var pres = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var presWidth = pres.getPageWidth();
  var presHeight = pres.getPageHeight();
  // Clear everything
  var slides = pres.getSlides()
  while (slides.length > 0) {
    slides.pop().remove();
  };
  // Add all images from Drive folder
  var parentId = DriveApp.getFileById(pres.getId()).getParents().next().getId();
  var srPicIter = DriveApp.searchFiles(
    '(mimeType contains "png" or mimeType contains "jpg" or mimeType contains "jpeg" or mimeType contains "bmp") and "' + parentId + '" in parents');
  while (srPicIter.hasNext()) {
    var file = srPicIter.next();
    // Place image on slide
    var image = pres.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BLANK).insertImage(file.getBlob());
    // Determine fit-to-page scale ratio
    if (image.getWidth()/image.getHeight() > presWidth/presHeight) {
      // Image is wider than slide
      var ratio = presWidth/image.getWidth();
    } else {
      // Image is taller than slide
      var ratio = presHeight/image.getHeight();
    };
    // Apply scaling ratio and align center
    image.scaleWidth(ratio).scaleHeight(ratio).alignOnPage(SlidesApp.AlignmentPosition.CENTER);
  };
};
```

Comment: Does it always fail on the same slide.

Comment: How big does the file get?

Comment: Perhaps the script is timing out.

Comment: @Cooper 1) The script doesn't always fail on the same slide -- it's only happened four times or so, and there doesn't seem to be a pattern in terms of location.  2) Since Slides files don't count against my Drive storage space, I can't actually see how large it is.  3) The script did time out once, at 360 seconds, but it usually doesn't get that far before the above error pops up.

Comment: Is the `id` for which the code is failing always the same? Is it the Id of the Slides document or of one (or several) of  the pictures?

Comment: @ziganotschka The ID provided in the error message is that of the Slides document, and is thus always the same.

Comment: The most likely reason for this error is that your presentation is over the [allowed limit of 100MB](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en). You can try to compress your images or other heavy components to minimize that presentation size.